# Angular ngif implementation issue, wont bind in div

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an issue where I cannot implement ngif in my Angular component. I have added it in my html-file as seen below:

```html
<div *ngif="!noTicketsAvailable">
  <h2 mat-dialog-title><i>Please pick a period for the PTD report</i></h2>
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Choose a start date</mat-label>
    <input required matInput [matDatepicker]="fromPicker" [(ngModel)]="data.fromDate">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="fromPicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #fromPicker></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Choose a end date</mat-label>
    <input required matInput [matDatepicker]="toPicker" [(ngModel)]="data.toDate">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="toPicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #toPicker></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>

  <div mat-dialog-actions>
    <button [disabled]="!(data.toDate && data.fromDate)" mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="data" cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
    <button mat-button (click)="onCloseClick()">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div *ngif="noTicketsAvailable">
  <h2 mat-dialog-title><i>No Tickets found for this period</i></h2>

  <div mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-button (click)="onCloseClick()">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

When lauching with Chrome in Development I get the follow error in the console:

```html
compiler.js:2426 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngif' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("<div [ERROR ->]*ngif="!noTicketsAvailable">
  <h2 mat-dialog-title><i>Please pick a period for the PTD report</i></"): ng:///AppModule/PTDperiodpickerComponent.html@0:5
Property binding ngif not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("[ERROR ->]<div *ngif="!noTicketsAvailable">
  <h2 mat-dialog-title><i>Please pick a period for the PTD report<"): ng:///AppModule/PTDperiodpickerComponent.html@0:0
Can't bind to 'ngif' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("
  </div>
</div>
<div [ERROR ->]*ngif="noTicketsAvailable">
  <h2 mat-dialog-title><i>No Tickets found for this period</i></h2>
```

I wonder if this is a div-specific issue or something else because I have ngif used in other html-files where it works. I don't think anything else needs to be imported but could be wrong. Can anyone suggest what might be the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have a casing issue. It should be `*ngIf` instead of `*ngif`

Comment: Thanks for the help! I need to be more careful of case sensitivity. Now it works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Per Kurt's comment, `Angular` uses `typescript` and it is `case sensitive`. `ngIf` is a `structural directive` in `angular` hence lower case `ngif` is not recognized.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I need to be more careful of case sensitivity. Now it works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred because you have a syntax error on your structural directive `*ngIf` in your HTML.

You wrote `*ngif` untill `*ngIf`

I let you check the [official documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#description) about *ngIf.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I need to be more careful of case sensitivity. Now it works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the answers already given that you should `*ngIf` instead of `*ngif` I suggest you use `<ng-container>` instead of a `<div>`.

Unless your `div` is using any css, it isn't necessary for the DOM to render it. So that's where `ng-container` comes in, it doesn't get rendered by the DOM. It's really useful with structural directives.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I need to be more careful of case sensitivity. Now it works as intended.